# Akka TypedActor - how to correctly handle async responses with context

Tags: scala, akka, actor, typedactor

I have begun working with TypedActors in Scala and have run into a problem doing something pretty simple: I want Actor A to call a method on Actor B and process the result within an anonymous function on Actor A, but ensuring that:

1. My response-handling function is thread-safe, e.g. will not run concurrently with any other threads accessing Actor A’s state

   My response-handling function can reference the context of Actor A

How can I (or can I) satisfy both of those requirements?

For example, this actor just wants to call an API on otherActor that returns a Future[Int], and update it's state with the result and then do something that requires it's actor context:

```
class MyActorImpl extends MyActor {

  // my mutable state
  var myNumber = 0

  // method proxied by TypedActor ref:
  def doStuff(otherActor: OtherActor): Unit = {
    otherActor.doOtherStuff onSuccess {
      // oops this is no longer running in MyActorImpl..
      // this could be on a concurrent thread if we
      case i => processResult(i)
    }
  }

  private def processResult(i: Int): Unit = {
    myNumber = 0 // oops, now we are possibly making a concurrent modification
    println(s"Got $i")

    // fails with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling TypedActor.context
    // outside of a TypedActor implementation method!
    println(s"My context is ${TypedActor.context}")
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to write my handler to call a method defined on the proxied interface to guarantee single-entry? That would seem ugly if I do not want to expose that particular “private” method (e.g. processResult) on an interface.

Here is a full version that will run in the Scala REPL:

```
import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent._

val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
import system.dispatcher

trait OtherActor {
  def doOtherStuff(): Future[Int]
}


trait MyActor {
  def doStuff(otherActor: OtherActor): Unit
}

class OtherActorImpl extends OtherActor {
  var i = 0
  def doOtherStuff(): Future[Int] = {
    i += 1
    Future {i} 
  }
}

class MyActorImpl extends MyActor {

  // my mutable state
  var myNumber = 0

  // method proxied by TypedActor ref:
  def doStuff(otherActor: OtherActor): Unit = {
    otherActor.doOtherStuff onSuccess {
      // oops this is no longer running in MyActorImpl..
      // this could be on a concurrent thread if we
      case i => processResult(i)
    }
  }

  private def processResult(i: Int): Unit = {
    myNumber = 0 // oops, now we are possibly making a concurrent modification
    println(s"Got $i")

    // fails with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling TypedActor.context
    // outside of a TypedActor implementation method!
    println(s"My context is ${TypedActor.context}")
  }
}

val actor1: MyActor = TypedActor(system).typedActorOf(TypedProps[MyActorImpl])
val actor2: OtherActor = TypedActor(system).typedActorOf(TypedProps[OtherActorImpl])

actor1.doStuff(actor2)
```

Comment: "my Future will complete with my TypedActor's dispatcher, thus preventing concurrent access to it's state" - I'm pretty sure this is false. The dispatcher could (and usually is) managing several threads, so concurrent access is possible.

Comment: Hm, good point. After reading http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/scala/futures.html#within-actors a little closer I see that it does not mention any single-entry guarantees. I think I'm going to revise the question...

Comment: @wingedsubmariner - thanks again. question has been revised... and simplified.

Comment: FWIW, the problem would go away if you follow the rule that each actor is responsible for changing its' own state, so ActorA would send a message to ActorB requesting a state change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exposing state of the Actor to outside world and that's a very bad thing. Look here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.3/general/jmm.html section *Actors and shared mutable state* lines 9-10 describe your case.

@philwalk already described how you could fix this problem: [Akka TypedActor - how to correctly handle async responses with context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306255/akka-typedactor-how-to-correctly-handle-async-responses-with-context#comment35850017_23306255)